# Вместо одного / в переменную сохраняются два /

Tags: c#

Почему в переменной `string slash = @"\";` сохраняется два `\`, и как это исправить?

Comment: Извините за тупые вопросы

Comment: "сохраняется два \" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor откладка visual studio сообщает

Comment: Маленький гномик вылез из Visual Studio и сообщил?

Comment: @Igor https://pastenow.ru/EL9DA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Там один слеш. Первый слеш (escape-индикатор для следующего символа) показывает, что идущий за ним слеш - это символ слеш, а не escape-индикатор для следующего символа.